# How execute encrypted bash script file in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a bash file and I want execute it by encrypted mode.

by using this command I encrypted my file.
now I want to run it. How could I do this?

```
openssl des3 -salt -in file.txt -out file.txt.enc -pass pass:password
```

Answer (score 0):

use `shc` script compiler to encrypt it (Blowfish), see this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/?utm_source=tuicool

[http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/117920/171](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/117920/171/)

http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/

If you want to use DES3 you can try the answer of *soFan* in this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90178/how-can-i-either-encrypt-or-render-my-shell-script-unreadable

write the wrapper `#!/bin/sh openssl enc -d -DES3 ... -a -in script-enc | sh -`